# Does wp_schedule_single_event create multiple events?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am a very strange problem. I am using Wordress 3.9.1 and in an admin's plugin i have this code:

```
function do_this_event_now() {
    for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++)
    {
        $my_post = array(
          'post_title'    => 'My post: '. date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
          'post_content'  => 'This is my post.',
          'post_status'   => 'publish',
          'post_author'   => 1,
          'post_category' => array(1)
        );

        // Insert the post into the database
        wp_insert_post( $my_post );

        sleep(50);
    }
}

add_action( 'my_new_event', 'do_this_event_now' );

wp_schedule_single_event( time(), 'my_new_event' );
```

It should create a post each 50 seconds. But the result is very strange.

I correctly see 5 posts but the titles ( where i write the `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` ) are really wrong:

```
My post: 2014-07-10 15:14:57
My post: 2014-07-10 15:15:47
My post: 2014-07-10 15:16:01
My post: 2014-07-10 15:16:38
My post: 2014-07-10 15:16:51
```

As you can see the differences are not 50 seconds!

How is this possible? This is a single event why this weird result?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Unlike the cron that most systems administrators are used to, WP-Cron isn't based off the server's clock, or even the server itself. Instead, there’s a check every time a person calls one of your pages or posts. Every time WordPress starts to render a page, it checks to see if there are any jobs that need to be run with WP-Cron. If your site doesn't get visited very often (like most development sites), your posts will not be created exactly every 50 seconds. You can change this by following a guide like this: http://www.kettlewellconsulting.com/2013/06/23/reliably-schedule-wordpress-tasks/ to turn off the default WP-Cron and implement your own cron job, so it is constantly creating those posts as you would like it to.

Comment: yes i understand what you mean... but here i execute the hook ONE TIME, then i create posts in a loop not scheduling other events. So i do not understand the reason.. When It starts then the posts should be created every 50 seconds exactly (after sleep(50) no?

Comment: @Dail the same rule still applies. Just because you use `wp_schedule_single_event` doesn't mean that it will always run exactly as you want to. Because you have a 50 second waiting period where the script waits to be told to run again, you will need someone visiting the site or you'll need something to simulate that for you, as I explained with the above link.